# Inlcuding a jsp in a dialog

Tags: jsp, user-interface, liferay, alloy-ui

I wish to include display a jsp page as an aui dialog in liferay, and at the moment I'm doing something like this:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="editURL" windowState="<%= WindowState.MAXIMIZED.toString() %>" >
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/edit.jsp"/>
    <portlet:param name="id" value="<%= id%>"/>
</portlet:renderURL>

<aui:script use="aui-dialog, aui-overlay-manager, dd-constrain">
    var editDialogOptions = {
        title: 'Dialog',
        bodyContent: '',
        centered: true,
        group: 'default',
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                label: 'Cancel',
                handler: function() {
                    this.close();
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    $("#btnEdit").on('click', function(event) {
        var editFeelingDialog = new A.Dialog(
            A.merge(editDialogOptions, {
                title: 'Edit Product'
            })
        ).plug(A.Plugin.IO, {uri: '<%= editURL %>'}).render();
    });
</aui:script>
```

The page renders, passing in my parameter, but it includes the entire control panel and miscellaneous information like the sign out link and the navigation etc that I do not want to display. Is there anyway to just display purely the edit.jsp page without everything else?

I would appreciate any help regarding this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to fix it by changing the windowState to "POP_UP".